# Ampscript multiple condition if empty and rowcount

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am trying to make an IF statement with two condition like this:

```
 %%[ 
 SET @PACKAGE_rows = Lookuporderedrows("TABLE","10","ORDER
 DESC","CRITERIA","True")  
 SET @USER_REGION_ID =
 lookup("CONTACTS","region_id","email",@USER_EMAIL) IF @USER_REGION_ID
 is not empty AND ROWCOUNT(@PACKAGE_rows)  > 1 THEN  
 ]%% 

 condition 1

 %%[ELSE]%% 

 condition 2 

 %%[ENDIF]%%
```

Even if my variable USER_REGION_ID is populated I always see the condition 2
I don't see what I am missing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'd be something like this:

```
 %%[ 

 SET @PACKAGE_rows = lookuporderedrows("TABLE","10","ORDER DESC","CRITERIA","True")  
 SET @USER_REGION_ID = lookup("CONTACTS","region_id","email", @USER_EMAIL) 

 IF not empty(@USER_REGION_ID) AND rowcount(@PACKAGE_rows) > 1 THEN  
 ]%% 

 condition 1

 %%[ELSE]%% 

 condition 2 

 %%[ENDIF]%%
```

**Reference**

- [**Empty()**](https://ampscript.guide/empty)